# How can I know if my sent email reach the receiver or not java?

Tags: java, email, apache-commons

I am using this code to send email

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
email.setSmtpPort(465);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("username", "password"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-)");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
email.send();
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html

How can I know if the foo@bar.com is real email and it receives the messages ?

```
 email.addTo("foo@bar.com");
```

Comment: In general, you can't know: some mail servers drop email, especially if they think it's spam.

Comment: Are you talking about running a test case to ensure the email reaches an email address that you control, or are you talking about the generic case of sending multiple emails and ensuring each of them reaches a real person?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reliable way to track email delivery without proprietary APIs and infrastructure. Based only on SMTP, POP and/or IMAP, there is no way to make completely sure, that the email was *read*.

There are options, however, that might give you some degree of information about the validity of the address (starting with an email address parser), listening to error messages that might get sent from the receiving server ([Bounce message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_delivery_report)) and requesting delivery notifications ([Return receipts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_tracking#Return-receipts)).

Additionally you could send an HTML email and embed a link to an image and track if the URL has been called. But even this is not reliable, because email clients might not display images, the URL might have been called by a virus scanner etc. That means you might get a lot of false positives / negatives.

Comment: I think the 1 pixel image url method does not work anymore on major email services. From what I saw, Gmail for example, parses the email and extracts images, and automatically uploads them to their servers (with their URL). I am not sure it happens for every image though, it would be good if someone could confirm or infirm this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the **POP3** capabilities of JavaMail.

You have a sample here: http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-pop-pop3-reader-email-inbox-example

I if remember well: server is **pop.gmail.com** and port is **995**.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for valid domain of the recipients id by doing something like

```
boolean result = true;

try {
  InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(email);
  emailAddr.validate();

} catch (AddressException ex) {
  result = false;
}
  return result;
```

**UPDATE**
Or else if you really want to ensure this, then there is some workaround of adding a header field to your html email, I dont remember exactly but something like

```
email.AddHeaderField("Disposition-Notification-To","<abc@xyz.com>");
```

could work in this case.

Comment: That's ... **very far** from ensuring the mail reached the desired recipient.

Comment: then there is no way to ensure that you always get the delivery or open-message notification.

Mailservers may accept the mail and drop it afterwards. users may read the mail but dismiss the notification.